# When will Microsoft release certification course for SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, certification

Does anyone know when certifications will be available for SharePoint 2016?

I saw few [courses](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/learning/course.aspx?cid=20339-2) on it , but are there any certifications available yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have released the certification/exam for Sharepoint Server 2016

Exam Number is **70-339** and is called **Managing Microsft SharePoint Server 2016.**

The 70-339 exam will be the only SharePoint exam required for the SharePoint 2016 MCSE certification.

[Managing SharePoint 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-339.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Amit
Any Developer certifications released?

Comment: Actually Microsft is retiring development certifications and  replacing with office 365 certifications...https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2016/02/microsoft-replacing-sharepoint-dev-certifications-office-365.html

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Amit's Answer.

Microsoft release SharePoint MCSE certification for SharePoint 2016, You can earn it via two.

**Method # 1** you have to pass the following exams.

1. Managing Office 365 Identities and Requirements(70-346)
2. Enabling Office 365 Services (70-347)
3. Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016(70-339)

**Mehtod 2** if you dont want Office 365 path then you can go Windows server( i did this way).

1. Installing and Configuring Windows Server 2012  (70-410)
2. Administering Windows Server 2012   (70-411)
3. Configuring Advanced Windows Server 2012 Services (70-412)
4. Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016 (70-339)

You can learn more about this here: [MCSE: SharePoint](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx)

.

Comment: Waqas so 70339 is included under MCSE correct ? Actually i have a MCP exam voucher and want to take 70339 exam . But i am not sure if 70339 exam is covered under MCP.